# Java, cannot find symbol : strange

Tags: java

Beginner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class T69 {

  static String S = new String();

  public static int makeInt(){
    int n=0;
    int tein=1;
    int i=S.lenght()-1;
    while(i>0){
      n+=tein*(int)S.charAt(i);
      tein*=10;
      i--;
    }
    return n;
  }

  public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    String S = cin.nextLine();
    int f = S.makeInt();  
  }
}
```

Error:

```
T69.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
int i=S.lenght()-1;
^
symbol: method lenght()
location: variable S of type String
T69.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
int f = S.makeInt();
^
symbol: method makeInt()
location: variable S of type String
2 errors
```

Answer (score 2):

To get your code to compile:

- Change `S.lenght()` to `S.length()`
- Change `int f = S.makeInt();` to `int f = makeInt();`

To get your code to working:

- Change `String S = cin.nextLine();` to `S = cin.nextLine();`.
- Change `n+=tein*(int)S.charAt(i);` to `n+=tein*(S.charAt(i) - '0');`

To get your code clean:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class T69 {

    public static int makeInt(String s){
      int n = 0;
      int tein = 1;
      int i = s.length() - 1;
      while (i > 0) {
        n += tein * (s.charAt(i) - '0');
        tein *= 10;
        i--;
      }
      return n;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
      Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
      int f = makeInt(cin.nextLine());  
      System.out.println(f)
    }
  }
```

BTW, you can make it even cleaner than that.

Comment: You accidentally left `s.lenght()` in your clean code :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you've misspelt `length` as `lenght`:

```
int i=S.lenght()-1;
```

Secondly, the way you're calling `makeInt()` is not correct, since it's not a member of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your method name.

Change

```
int i=S.lenght()-1;
```

to

```
int i=S.length()-1;
```

And you are invoking the `makeInt()` incorrectly.

Change

```
int f = S.makeInt();
```

to

```
int f = makeInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

> int i=S.lenght()-1;

change to

> int i=S.length()-1;